# Trying to make custom Android kernel, but won't boot up details inside

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

So as per this entry:

https://sites.google.com/site/zhuoweisite/blog/newlocationoflastkmsgonandroid60andabovesysfspstoreconsole-ramoops

It states:

On Android, diagnosing kernel crashes often requires a developer to read the /proc/last_kmsg file, which stores previous kernel logs after a reboot. Unfortunately it went missing in Android 6.0.

It turns out that it was moved to /sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops . It still works the same way as before (cat /sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops will display the previous kernel log)

So I pushed the command to see the last kernel message and it seems towards the end it just randomly restarts itself, I'm not sure if am reading it write, but here is the last few outputs:

```
    [    6.097377,1] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:icon_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.098509,1] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:mpctl_data_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.301920,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Nothing to do in chg_check_timer
    [    6.347049,1] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:ringtone_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.554054,2] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:cache_private_backup_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.555826,2] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:battery_data_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.556760,2] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:hwrev_data_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.558415,2] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:cnd_data_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.560026,2] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:time_data_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.566163,2] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:rfs_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.568242,2] SELinux:  Context u:object_r:rfs_shared_hlos_file:s0 is not valid (left unmapped).
    [    6.570286,2] audit_printk_skb: 30 callbacks suppressed
    [    6.570295,2] type=1400 audit(106705.339:21): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  uid=0 pid=342 comm="recovery" kmod="fs-auto" scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=1
    [    6.570474,0] type=1400 audit(106705.339:22): avc:  denied  { execute } for  uid=0 pid=385 comm="kworker/u12:5" name="busybox" dev="rootfs" ino=11206 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
    [    6.570532,0] type=1400 audit(106705.339:23): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  uid=0 pid=385 comm="kworker/u12:5" path="/sbin/busybox" dev="rootfs" ino=11206 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
    [    8.084611,4] type=1400 audit(106706.859:24): avc:  denied  { write } for  uid=0 pid=342 comm="recovery" name="mmcblk0p27" dev="tmpfs" ino=15000 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
    [    8.161411,4] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
    [    8.162330,4] type=1400 audit(1488254358.584:25): avc:  denimd  { create } for  uid=0 pid=342 comm="recovery" name="orsin" scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=fifo_file permissive=1
    [    8.162376,4] type=1400 audit(1488254358.584:26): avc:  denied  { read } for  uid=0 pid=342 comm="recovery" name="orsin" dev="rootfs" ino=15397 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=fifo_file permissive=1
    [    8.162399,4] type=1400 audit(1488254358.584:27): avc:  denied  { open } for  uid=0 pid=342 comm="recovery" path="/sbin/orsin" dev="rootfs" ino=15397 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=fifo_file permissive=1
    [    8.954167,0] type=1400 audit(1488254359.384:28): avc:  denied  { write } for  uid=0 pid=400 comm="recovery" name="mtp_usb" dev="tmpfs" ino=15274 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mtp_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
    [    8.954198,0] mtp_open
    [   10.216600,5] FG: fg_batt_profile_init: Battery SOC: 62
    [   11.680545,0] qpnp-smbcharger qpnp-smbcharger-ffffffc0b00fb000: Battery Temp State = Good
    [   42.890682,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   42.890757,2] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   42.890785,1] mtp_release
    [   42.890817,1] mtp_open
    [   42.891520,2] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac10524° was not queued to ep0out
    [   42.891561,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   42.891629,3] read descriptors
    [   42.891640,3] read strings
    [   42.891665,3] mtp_bind_config
    [   43.042547,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   43.046142,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   43.210343,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   43.211197,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   43.211274,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   43.215391,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   43.215434,1] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   43.216266,1] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   43.216379,3] read descriptors
    [   43.216390,3] read strings
    [   43.216413,3] mtp_bind_config
    [   43.272597,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   43.272649,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   43.367546,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   43.371147,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   43.535367¬0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   43.535858,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   43.535933,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   43.591966,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   43.717307,0] type=1400 audit(1488254394.134:29): avc:  denied  { ioctl } for  uid=0 pid=400 comm="recovery" path="/dev/mtp_usb" dev="tmpfs" ino=15274 ioctlcmd=4d04 scontext=u:r:knit:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mtp_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
    [   43.717401,1] type=1400 audit(1488254394.134:30): avc:  denied  { read } for  uid=0 pid=299 comm="kworker/u12:5" path="/data/media/0/Android/Q-kernel.zip" dev="mmcblk0p48" ino=8037 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:media_rw_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
    [   50.608979,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   50.609048,2] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   50.609068,1] mtp_release
    [   50.609105,1] mtp_open
    [   50.60)804,2] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   50.609837,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   50.609913,3] read descriptors
    [   50.609923,3] read strings
    [   50.609947,3] mtp_bind_config
    [   50.761526,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   50.765150,0] android_work: anlroid_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   50.929363,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   50.929695,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   50.929770,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   50.981967,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   54.498818,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   54.498905,1] mtp_release
    [   54.49893),1] mtp_open
    [   54.498980,1] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   54.499726,1] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   54.499761,0] android_work:"android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   54.499835,3] read descriptors
    [   54.499845,3] read strings
    [   54.499869,3] mtp_bind_config
    [   54.651640,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   54.655184,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   54.819494,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   54.819615,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   54.819691,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   54.823547,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   54.823589,1] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   54.824424,1] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   54.824535,3] read descriptors
    [   54.824546,3] read strings
    [   54.824569,3] mtp_bind_config
    [   54.872616,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   54.872659,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   54.975480,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   54.979123,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   55.143295,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   55.143679,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config +1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   55.143754,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   55.202043,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   67.895472,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   67.895547,2] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   67.895569,1] mtp_release
    [   67.895595,1] mtp_open
    [   67.896279,2] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   67.896326,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   67.896502,0] read descriptors
    [   67.896513,0] read strings
    [   67.896540,0] mtp_bind_c/nfig
    [   68.047392,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   68.051022,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   68.215236,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   68.215816,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   68.215891,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   68.219944,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   68.219986,1] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   68.220818,1] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   68.220927,0] read descriptors
    [   68.220938,0] read strings
    [   68.220963,0] mtp_bind_config
    [   68.271986,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   68.272043,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   68.372371,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   68.376016,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   68.540507,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   68.540628,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   68.540705,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   68.591964,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   71.435928,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   71.435998,2] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   71.436018,1] mtp_release
    [   71.436052,1] mtp_open
    [   71.4³6748,2] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   71.436782,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   71.436860,1] read descriptors
    [   71.436872,1] read strings
    [   71.436896,1] mtp_bind_config
    [   71.588361,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   71.591996,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   71.756266,0] android_work: androi`_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   71.756507,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   71.756583,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   71.811973,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   72.913049,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   72.913106,1] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   72.913154,0] mtp_release
    [   72.913180,0] mtp_open
    [   72.913803,1] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   72.913896,0] read descriptors
    [   72.913907,0] read strings
    [   72.913930,0] mtp_bind_config
    [   72.914750,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   73.065495,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   73.069033,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   73.233409,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   73.233636,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   73.233714,0] dwc3 f920°000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   73.237905,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   73.237946,1] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   73.238786,1] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 as not queued to ep0out
    [   73.238898,0] read descriptors
    [   73.238909,0] read strings
    [   73.238932,0] mtp_bind_config
    [   73.292604,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   73.292646,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   73.390374,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   73.393932,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   73.558253,0] android_sork: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   73.558516,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   73.558593,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   73.611963,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   77.040761,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   77.040833,2] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   77.040846,1] mtp_release
    [   77.040871,1] mtp_open
    [   77.041587,2] dwc3 f9200800.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   77.041617,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   77.041689,1] read descriptors
    [   77.041699,1] read strings
    [   77.041723,1] mtp_bind_config
    [   77.193297,0] android_work: an$roid_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   77.196857,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   77.361108,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   77.361624,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   77.361700,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   77.421956,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [   80.912204,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [   80.912273,1] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [   80.912332,0] mtp_release
    [   80.912353,0] mtp_open
    [   80.913038,1] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [   80.913147,0] read descriptors
    [   80.913158,0] read strings
    [   80.913182,0] mtp_bind_config
    [   80.914317,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   81.064589,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   81.068043,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [   81.232340,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [   81.232603,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [   81.232678,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [   81.291968,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [  160.211107,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 2
    [  160.211165,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=SUSPENDED
    [  160.342014,2] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [  160.342049,1] mtp_release
    [  160.342066,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [  160.342072,1] mtp_open
    [  160.342084,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [  160.342098,2] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [  160.342335,3] read descriptors
    [  160.342348,3] read strings
    [  160.342373,3] mtp_bind_config
    [  160.342661,0] msm_bam_device_lpm_ok: Going to LPM now
    [  160.346395,0] msm-dwc3 f9200000.ssusb: DWC3 in low power mode
    [  168.609874,0] qpnp-smbcharger qpnp-smbcharger-ffffffc0b00fb000: HW Detected SDP!
    [  168.610592,0] qpnp-smbcharger qpnp-smbcharger-ffffffc0b00fb000: Normal Charger Detected!
    [  169.602000,0] qpnp-smbcharger qpnp-smbcharger-ffffffc0b00fb000: Start APSD Rerun!
    [  170.607525,0] msm-dwc3 f9200000.ssusb: DWC3 exited from low power mode
    [  170.872804,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [  170.876385,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [  171.040743,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [  171.041611,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [  171.041695,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [  171.101970,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [  172.601916,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Nothing to do in chg_check_timer
    [  182.729690,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [  182.729758,1] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [  182.730333,2] mtp_release
    [  182.730361,2] mtp_open
    [  182.730512,1] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to ep0out
    [  182.730578,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [  182.730627,1] read descriptors
    [  182.730637,1] read strings
    [  182.730660,1] mtp_bind_config
    [  182.881727,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [  182.885307,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [  183.049514,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [  183.050604,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [  183.050680,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [  183.101958,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFIGURED
    [  209.262540,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 0
    [  209.262610,1] ffs_epfile_io(): Error: returning -19 value
    [  "09.263191,2] mtp_release
    [  209.263222,2] mtp_open
    [  209.263355,1] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: request ffffffc0ac105240 was not queued to åp0out
    [  209.263400,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [  209.263461,0] read descriptors
    [  209.263472,0] read strings
    [  209.263495,0] mtp_bind_config
    [  209.415588,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [  209.419185,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
    [  209.583516,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONNECTED
    [  209.583768,0] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: fe80f0c8.android_usb
    [  209.583846,0] dwc3 f9200000.dwc3: Avail curr from USB = 500
    [  209.641959,0] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=CONFKGURED
    [  232.891342,0] type=1400 audit(1488254583.304:31): avc:  denied  { write } for  uid=0 pid=299 comm="kworker/u12:5" path="/data/media/0/Android/Q-kernel.zip" dev="mmcblk0p48" ino=8068 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:media_rw_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
    [  243.326142,0] type=1400 audit(1488254593.744:32): avc:  denied  { reîame } for  uid=0 pid=440 comm="recovery" name="__properties__" dev="tmpfs" ino=12646 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:properties_device:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
    [  243.329379¬1] type=1400 audit(1488254593.744:33): avc:  denied  { execute } for  uid=0 pid=441 comm="recovery" name="updater" dev="tmpfs" ino=16467 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_tmpfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
    [  243.329462,1] type=1400 audit(1488254593.744:34): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  uid=0 pid=441 comm="recovery" path="/tmp/updater" dev="tmpfs" ino=16467 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_tmpfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
    [  243.827589,1] mdss_dsi_ioctl_handler: unsupport ioctl =0x5413
    [  243.946354,1] EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p47): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (40)
    [  243.946718,1] EXT2-fs (mmcblk0p47): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (40)
    [  243.949143,0] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [  243.959655,1] type=1400 audit(1488254594.374:35): avc:  denied  { mounton } for  uid=0 pid=454 comm="mount" path="/data" dev="mmcblk0p48" ino=3 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
    [  244.127845,0] type=1400 audit(1488254594.544:36): avc:  denied  { create } for  uid=0 pid=497 comm="busybox" name="[" scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tmpfs:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=1
    [  244.160008,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.174590,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.194397,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.214460,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.234387,3] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.254408,3] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.274428,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.294455,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.314687,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.334416,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.354494,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.374810,2] msm_rng:Data not available!
    [  244.380839,1] mdss_dsi_ioctl_handler: unsupport ioctl =0x5413
    [  244.690785,0] type=1400 audit(1488254595.104:37): avc:  denied  { ioctl } for  uid=0 pid=828 comm="gunzip" path="/tmp/anykernel/split_img/boot.im'-ramdisk.gz" dev="tmpfs" ino=12679 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_tmpfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
    [  244.796647,0] mdss_dsi_ioctl_handler: unsupport ioctl =0x5413
    [  244.806381,0] mdss_dsi_ioctl_handler: unsupport ioctl =0x5413
    [  246.088877,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Mitigating CPU5 frequency to 768000
    [  246.129146,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Removing frequency mitigation for CPU5
    [  246.213383,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Mitigating CPU5 frequency to 768000
    [  246.246341,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Removing frequency mitigation for CPU5
    [  246.484422,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Mitigating CPU5 frequency to 768000
    [  246.506405,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Removing frequency mitigation for CPU5
    [  246.718815,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Mitigating CPU5 frequency to 768000
    [  246.755432,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Removing frequency mitigation for CPU5
    [  246.817695,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Mitigating CPU5 frequency to 768000
    [  246.850655,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Removing frequency mitigation for CPU5
    [  246.916582,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Mitigating CPU5 nrequency to 768000
    [  246.949543,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Removing frequency mitigation for CPU5
    [  247.015471,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Mitigating CPU5 frequency to 768000
    [  247.048430,0] msm_thermal:freq_mitigation_notify Removing frequency mitigation for CPU5
    [  250.770647,1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
    [  250.771410,1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): re-mounted. Opts: data=ordered
    [  250.793466,1] type=1400 audit(1488254601.214:38): avc:  denied  { setattr } for  uid=0 pid=858 comm="chown" name="modules" dev="mmcblk0p47" ino=1355 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_rºsystem_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1400 audit(1488254601.274:39): avc:  denied  { unlink } for  uid=0 pid=867 comm="rm" name="bugreports" dev="tmpfs" ino=2318 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tãontext=u:object_r:tmpfs:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=1
    [  251.408002,0] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is rekommended
    [  251.408218,1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
    [  251.436115,1] type=1400 audit(1488254601.854:40): avc:  denied  { mounton } for  uid=0 pid=873 comm="mount" path="/sdcard" dev="mmcblk0p48" ino=7 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:media_rw_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
    [  254.145694,4] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): warning: m!ximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
    [  254.145882,4] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
    [  254.152574¬4] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): warning: maximal mount count reached, rujning e2fsck is recommended
    [  254.152749,4] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
    [  254.231987,5] SysRq : Emergency Remount R/O
    [  254.276840,1] Emergency Remount complete
    [  255.462366,0] mdss_fb_release_all: try to close unopened fb 1! from pid:1 name:init
    [  255.462921,1] mdss_mdp_overlay_release_sub: Unable to unset pipe(s) ndx=0x8 unset=0x0
    [  255.463431,0] isl98611 backlight off 
    [  255.501352,1] mdss_dsi_panel_off[0]+.
    [  255.574506,1] mdss_dsi_off[0]+.
    [  255.590252,1] mdss_dsi_panel_off[1]+.
    [  255.590666,1] mdss_dsi_off[1]+.
    [  255.606402,0] Restarting system with command ''.
    [  255.606414,0] Current task:init(1) Parent task:swapper/0(0)
    [  255.606434,0] Going down for restart now
    [  255.607062,0] qcom,qpnp-power-on ppnp-power-on-ffffffc0b00f9c00:(PMIC@SID2: configuring PON for reset
    1
    [  250.836048,1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): re-mounted. Opts: data=ordered
    [  250.857247,0] type=1400 audit(1488254601.274:39): avc:  denied  { unlink } for  uid=0 pid=867 comm="rm" name="bugreports" dev="tmpfs" ino=2318 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tãontext=u:object_r:tmpfs:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=1
    [  251.408002,0] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is rekommended
    [  251.408218,1] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
    [  251.436115,1] type=1400 audit(1488254601.854:40): avc:  denied  { mounton } for  uid=0 pid=873 comm="mount" path="/sdcard" dev="mmcblk0p48" ino=7 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:media_rw_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
    [  254.145694,4] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): warning: m!ximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
    [  254.145882,4] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
    [  254.152574¬4] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): warning: maximal mount count reached, rujning e2fsck is recommended
    [  254.152749,4] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p47): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
    [  254.231987,5] SysRq : Emergency Remount R/O
    [  254.276840,1] Emergency Remount complete
    [  255.462366,0] mdss_fb_release_all: try to close unopened fb 1! from pid:1 name:init
    [  255.462921,1] mdss_mdp_overlay_release_sub: Unable to unset pipe(s) ndx=0x8 unset=0x0
    [  255.463431,0] isl98611 backlight off 
    [  255.501352,1] mdss_dsi_panel_off[0]+.
    [  255.574506,1] mdss_dsi_off[0]+.
    [  255.590252,1] mdss_dsi_panel_off[1]+.
    [  255.590666,1] mdss_dsi_off[1]+.
    [  255.606402,0] Restarting system with command ''.
    [  255.606414,0] Current task:init(1) Parent task:swapper/0(0)
    [  255.606434,0] Going down for restart now
    [  255.607062,0] qcom,qpnp-power-on ppnp-power-on-ffffffc0b00f9c00:(PMIC@SID2: configuring PON for reset
```

The full log is here:

https://gist.github.com/MikeUYSCUTI/d7093164920e8d908bda211c8f8a1012

Comment: You have issues with mmcblk0p47. By the way kernel boots okay.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i get a boot loop but thanks let me check out options for the mmcblk0p47 issue